# WPF: Convert string to UI Element

Tags: c#, wpf, string, xaml, visual-studio-2013

Here's what i'm trying to do: I have lots of paths that are acting as buttons, I wanted to change the fill color of any of them on mouse over and mouse exit. To do so, I wanted to create a function that scans the name of the current path that the mouse entered, store it in a variable or string, and then use that to change the fill color.

The Problem is: I have no idea how to cast the string to an UI Element, nothing that used to work on Windows Forms seems to work on WPF. The code that retrieves the name of the element does work fine.

```
private void MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var mouseWasDownOn = e.Source as FrameworkElement;
        if (mouseWasDownOn != null)
        {
            string elementName = mouseWasDownOn.Name;

            [no idea what goes here].Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 193, 194, 194));     
        }


    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `((Path)sender).Fill = ...`

Comment: The phrase "cast the string to an UI Element" doesn't make sense. What do you have in the string? It looks like you mean "name of the current path that the mouse entered", but I don't know what that means either.

Comment: I think you could use trigger to achieve your goal, can you provide some XAML code to help me answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Clemens.

This is the answer:

```
private void MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var mouseWasDownOn = e.Source as FrameworkElement;
    if (mouseWasDownOn != null)
    {
        string elementName = mouseWasDownOn.Name;

        ((Path)mouseWasDownOn).Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 193, 194, 194));     
    }


}
```

Or shorter:

```
private void MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ((Path)sender).Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 193, 194, 194));  
}
```